# Error correction on $n$ qubits all in same state except for a few

Tags: quantum-state, error-correction

This might be a straightforward problem for you guys; it would be helpful if you can explain it in simple language.

I have $n$-qubits given as
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|0\rangle+ e^{\iota\theta_{1}}|1\rangle \right) \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|0\rangle+ e^{\iota\theta_{2}}|1\rangle \right) \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|0\rangle+ e^{\iota\theta_{3}}|1\rangle \right) \otimes \cdots \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|0\rangle+e^{\iota\theta_{n}}|1\rangle \right)$$
where $\theta_i$'s are same except for only a few $\theta$s which are diffferent from rest.

How to apply an error correction on these states to correct those tiny fractions of $\theta$ to get all qubits in the same state?

For simplest case if I have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|0\rangle+ e^{\iota\theta}|1\rangle \right) \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|0\rangle+ e^{\iota\theta}|1\rangle \right) \otimes \cdots \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|0\rangle+ e^{\iota\beta}|1\rangle \right) \otimes \cdots \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|0\rangle+e^{\iota\theta}|1\rangle \right)$$
all same but the $i$th $\theta$ is different, then how to correct that qubit?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you try to do is impossible, because it violates the [no-cloning theorem](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-Cloning-Theorem). Note that what you want to do is not the standard way to do quantum error correction, because you have $n-1$ copies of a state, not an encoded state. If you have some more knowledge about the state, you might want to look into stuff like magic state distillation, e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403025).

One more comment: If $n$ is large you might be able to determine $\theta$, then prepare $n$ new copies of the state.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how possible what you described is. I think the best you can possibly do is to project into the $n$ qubit symmetric space by applying

$$\text{SymmetricProjector}(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left|{n \atop k}\right\rangle\left\langle{n \atop k}\right|$$

where the "n choose k state" is the superposition of all n-bit numbers with k bits set:

$$\left|{n \atop k}\right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n \choose k}} \sum_{x \in \left\{{n \atop k}\right\}} |x\rangle$$

$$\left\{{n \atop k}\right\} = \left\{x \in \mathbb{Z} | 0 \leq x < 2^n \land \text{HammingWeight}(x) = k \right\}$$

But that's more of an error *detection* scheme than an error correction scheme (because the projection can fail), and honestly it won't work particularly well.

---

A similar process that *is* possible is [magic state distillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_state_distillation). The key differences that make it work are that the target state is known, and the number of output states is less than the number of input states.